# how to retrieve a number from a string contating separators in pl/sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to retrieve origin number(8385) from this type of string:
// slv is a varchar, containing the string

```
slv=
DEFAULTLOCALE=S=en_GBORIGIN=L=8385WORKGROUP=L=3MAINORIGIN=L=183CLAIMID=L=7416882
```

Separators used here are NAK(negative acknowledge) and ESC(escape).
Also, please note that this string is a template, and the length of the origin number, might vary. So i cant use a fixed code like :

`substr(slv,instr(slv,'ORIGIN=L=',1)+9,4);` //because this will fetch fixed 4 places, and the origin number might vary to 3 or even 5.

Please suggest.
TIA

PS- This has to be in pl/sql or sql.

Answer (score 4):

Using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` we can try the following:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('DEFAULTLOCALE=S=en_GBORIGIN=L=8385WORKGROUP=L=3MAINORIGIN=L=183CLAIMID=L=7416882',
        'GBORIGIN=L=(\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) origin
FROM dual

8385
```

### Demo

Comment: Please tell me how to store this data into a variable, that i ultimately want to print. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @VaibhavOberoi I'm not an Oracle expert.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it in PL/SQL, since you mentioned in a comment that you want to be able to save it in a variable in order to print it:

```
declare
  v_slv varchar2(100) := 'DEFAULTLOCALE=S=en_GBORIGIN=L=8385WORKGROUP=L=3MAINORIGIN=L=183CLAIMID=L=7416882';
  v_origin varchar2(8);
BEGIN
  v_origin := REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_slv, 'GBORIGIN=L=(\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1);

  dbms_output.put_line('Origin is: ' || v_origin);
END;
```

Comment: Hi sir. there are separators in between this string. Separators are 'NAK' and 'ESC', which mean negative acknowledge and escape respectively. It is not working when separators are there.

Comment: Where exactly are the separators?  Please update your original post to indicate them.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(str,'[[:digit:]]+') str FROM
(
 SELECT 'slv=DEFAULTLOCALE=S=en_GBORIGIN=L=8385WORKGROUP=L=3MAINORIGIN=L=183CLAIMID=L=7416882' str FROM dual
)
/
```

Output: 8385

Answer (score 0):

`Declare
      v_val varchar2(255) -- if you just want to print it
    BEGIN
      SELECT 
REGEXP_SUBSTR('slv=DEFAULTLOCALE=S=en_GBORIGIN=L=8385WORKGROUP=L=3MAINORIGIN=L=183CLAIMID=L=7416882','[0-9]+',1,1)  into v_val FROM
dual;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ("output" || v_val);
    END;`

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for the solution. Please help me by telling where exactly is the code for picking up 'origin' ? How would i pick up the workgroup?